# Angular RxJS prevent double API calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to re-use the result of an RxJS stream without executing it again.

In a component I have to Input() streams: `query$` and `category$`. I want to convert that into two streams that share the same API source. Right now it is making two requests. I'd like to have only one request.

Simplified code:

```
this.searchResults$ = this.query$
  .switchMap((query) => this.httpClient.get(`/whatever?q=${query}`));

this.filteredSearchResults$ = Observable
  .combineLatest(this.searchResults$, this.category$)
  .filter(([ searchResults, category ]) => {
    // Code to make a subset

    return ['a', 'subset'];
  });
```

I consume both searchResults$ and filteredSearchResults$ in the same component:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(searchResults$ | async) as searchResults">
  <ng-container *ngIf="(filteredSearchResults$ | async) as filteredSearchResults">
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Now I understand why there are two API calls. I just don't see any way to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `share`:

```
this.searchResults$ = this.query$
  .switchMap((query) => this.httpClient.get(`/whatever?q=${query}`))
  .share(); <-- HERE

this.filteredSearchResults$ = Observable
  .combineLatest(this.searchResults$, this.category$)
  .filter(([ searchResults, category ]) => {
    // Code to make a subset

    return ['a', 'subset'];
  });
```

Comment: It's now working partially. On pageload both streams work as expected. But as soon as one of query$ or category$ changes I am getting an extra request with the old values. As well as a normal request with the new values.